# How can I make this javascript form validation DRYer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

The user has to select one radio from each of three input "categories". If he "submits" without doing so, he gets a warning:

http://jsfiddle.net/bqyvS/

Markup like this:

```
<form>
    <div id="color">
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="blue">
        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="red">
        <label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="green">      
        <label for="green">Green</label>
    </div>
    <div id="shape">
        <input type="radio" name="shape" id="square">
        <label for="square">Square</label>
        <input type="radio" name="shape" id="circle">
        <label for="circle">Circle</label>
        <input type="radio" name="shape" id="triangle">
        <label for="triangle">Triangle</label>
    </div>
    <div id="size">
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="small">
        <label for="small">Small</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="medium">
        <label for="mediume">Medium</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="large">      
        <label for="large">Large</label>
    </div>
  </form>
<a id="link" href="#">click me to "submit"</a>
<p id="warning"></p>​
```

Javascript:

```
$('#link').on('click', function() {
   if (!$('#color input[type=radio]:checked').length) {
      $('#warning').html("Oops! Please choose a color!"); 
   }
   else if(!$('#shape input[type=radio]:checked').length) {
      $('#warning').text("Oops! Please choose a shape!"); 
   }
   else if(!$('#size input[type=radio]:checked').length) {
     $('#warning').text("Oops! Please choose a size!"); 
   } 
});
```

This is a simplified version of a larger piece of code. How can I rewrite the conditional more efficiently so that I'm not verbosely checking each input name? (There should only be one "warning" displayed per "submit", even if multiple input name categories aren't checked.) Editing the markup would be okay.

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using actual HTML form elements, like <select> or <radio> and then you can just make sure that any elements within the form (one level down) have a selected="selected" attribute in each.

Comment: Thanks, but the only documentation on <radio> elements that I can find is MDN's page on XUL. I don't know a thing about XUL. Why not just input[type=radio]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying behavior to similar groups, you should start thinking about classes instead of ids, in this solution, you don't need a separate data-name but I believe it's better to have data separate from html id, but you could use this.id if you prefer

```
<form>
    <div id="color" class="selection-group" data-name="color">
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="blue">
        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="red">
        <label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="green">      
        <label for="green">Green</label>
    </div>
    <div id="shape" class="selection-group" data-name="square">
        <input type="radio" name="shape" id="square">
        <label for="square">Square</label>
        <input type="radio" name="shape" id="circle">
        <label for="circle">Circle</label>
        <input type="radio" name="shape" id="triangle">
        <label for="triangle">Triangle</label>
    </div>
    <div id="size" class="selection-group" data-name="size">
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="small">
        <label for="small">Small</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="medium">
        <label for="mediume">Medium</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="large">      
        <label for="large">Large</label>
    </div>
  </form>
<a id="link" href="#">click me to "submit"</a>
<p id="warning"></p>​
```

Javascript:

```
$('#link').on('click', function() {
   $('.selection-group').each(function() {
      if(!$(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length) {
          $('#warning').html("Oops! Please choose a "+ $(this).data('name') +"!"); 
          return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince looks good!! just not sure we need to repeat the message in data-message, I would probably end up using it if it turns out that we need different messages, which would probably end up being the case in a real world example

Comment: Very simple. Thank you. There's just one wrinkle: at http://jsfiddle.net/bqyvS/6/ when I click "submit" with no radios checked, I get the "size" warning first. For usability, I would like the warnings to appear in the order of the markup. In other words, "color" should be first. How can I direct the "sequence" of the each() function?

Comment: @Ben I added a return false to the each, which will break from the loop as soon as it finds a group that is missing a selection, that should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks , but that doesn't actually work. Try http://jsfiddle.net/bqyvS/7/ Click the submit anchor, then choose a color, then click the submit anchor again. The "color" message doesn't change.

Comment: @Ben You just forget the curly brakets around the if block, so the return false is executed regardless of an error being found or not!

Answer (score 2):

```
function validationCheck() {
    var isValid = true,
        errorText = "";
    $("form div").each(  //get the divs that hold the radios and loop
    //$("#color, #shape, #size").each( //could do it by ids of the divs also
        function(){
            var div = jQuery(this),  //div reference
                isChecked = div.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length>0;  //see if we have anything selected
            if (!isChecked) {  //if no selections, show error message
                isValid = false;  //set validation to false
                errorText = "Oops! Please choose a " + div.prop("id") + "!";  //build error message
                return false;  //exit each loop
            }
        }
    );
    $('#warning').text(errorText); //set error message
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to clear the error message at the beginning of the check so that it doesn't give the user a "false positive".

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){
  $('#color, #shape, #size').each(function(i, ele){
      if($(this).find('input:checked').length == 0)
        $('#warning').text("Oops! Please choose a " + this.id + "!");
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnFs5/)

You may want to consider generating a warning message in the case a user does not select any inputs or only 1 input.

In this example, a user will recieve a message similar to `Oops! Please choose a color, and shape!`

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){
  var msgs = [];

  $('#color, #shape, #size').each(function(i, ele){
    if($(this).find('input:checked').length == 0)
      msgs.push(this.id);
  });

  if(msgs.length > 0)
    $('#warning').text("Oops! Please choose a " + msgs.join(", and "));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnFs5/2/)